# amp cdn & cors requests to resources

Tags: cors, amp-html

I am working on a project where protecting resources (here: webfonts) is a legal requirement and CORS is considered sufficient. Accessing CORS protected resources seems impossible through the AMP CDN.

## how we handle cors at the origin

For protected resources, we check the `Origin:` request header against a regular expression and generate a matching `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` response header for a match plus `Vary: Origin` always.

In essence (simplified, reduced example):

- `curl -H 'Orgin: https://allowed.domain' -I https://site/.../font.woff2`

->

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=26680348
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://allowed.domain
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
```

- `curl -H 'Orgin: https://evil.domain' -I https://site/.../font.woff2`

->

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=26680348
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
```

This is plain simple CORS.

## how the amp cdn behaves

Now when I fire the same request against the corresponding AMP CDN URL...

```
curl -H 'Orgin: https://allowed.domain' -I https://site.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/site/.../font.woff2
```

I see a request coming in with

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Google-AMPHTML)
```

from an IP resolving to `google-proxy-*.google.com`, *but neither an `Origin:` nor an `AMP-Same-Origin:` request header*. Yet the way I read https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md#pseudo-cors-logic I should expect at least either.

It does not seem to matter if Origin: ends with `cdn.ampproject.org`, the cdn does not seem to forward it.

Consequently, our origin responds with 200 and no A-C-A-O as illustrated above.

Even more confusingly, the amp cdn sends this response downstream:

```
HTTP/2 404 
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-content-type-options: nosniff
...
```

So, how is CORS supposed to work with resources on the AMP CDN?

Comment: Try to check in the documentation about [CORS in AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests). 'This document explains the key aspects of using CORS in AMP'. Hope it will help enlighten you.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I did read it and it covers this topic, yet the CDN does not behave as expected. In particular, the fact that it does not forward the Origin header is not covered and appears to me to be plain wrong.

Comment: Now also reported via github: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an actual AMP CDN issue. I have worked 1:1 with contacts from google, who have resolved the issue.

Additionally, our origin did not send a `Content-Type` response header, which is required.